# Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zza found

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

The app was working perfectly when I did some changes last time. but suddenly getting the issue of firebase.

```
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    ..... other dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.1.0
```

getting error

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zza found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzb found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzc found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzd found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zze found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzf found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzh found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzm found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzn found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzo found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzp found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzq found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzr found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.1.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Comment: It looks like some of the firebase libraries you use are quite old. Try to update all of them to the latest version.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had same problem here, suddenly android stop work. I'm using react-native 0.61.5.

Here three ways you can solve this issue:

**First way: (solved my problem)**
On your **android/build.gradle** add this line to ext section:

```
firebaseVersion = "21.1.0"
```

**Second way: (also solved my problem)**
If the first way not work, maybe you should have to do a little bit more. In your **android/buld.gradle**:

```
  firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
   buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
   firebaseCoreVersion = "17.0.0"
   firebaseVersion = "21.1.0"
```

on your **android/app/build.gradle**, add this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
```

**Third way**

You will need to find all dependencies of firebase that are brake your application, pay attention for you node_modules dependencies that are using something related to firebase. Once you have all dependencies mapped, you will need to specify versions on your **android/build.gradle** and **android/app/build.gradle**.

**Notes:**
Sorry for my english, i tried.

Comment: I tried the second way, and it worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: The second way was the one that worked for me too. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

i was having this issue, i found that firebase-iid worked on the same version than firebase-messaging, but now the messaging version is 22.0.0 and the mayor version of firebase-iid is 21.1.0, so yo have to separate the dependencies with each corresponding version.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: On your build gradle(app) use:
`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"`

Or now i'm usin firebase BoM to to keep dependencies updated
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=en 
On the step 4 is the detail of that.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasBeltrami , firebase BoM  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Used below firebase-messaging version
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

removing `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics` on your

**android/app/build.gradle**